# jquery remove content inside a tag 'x' but before tag 'y'

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a command to clean the beginning of content inside my form

but I would like to preserve last elements (that are some buttons (tag a)

```
$('#Detail form').not('a').html('');
```

is not working

Comment: Show your markup. (Obviously! :-) )

Comment: Using the `a` tag instead of `button` when you want to get a button is not a really good idea.

Comment: unfortunately I need to use jquerymobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the children of the `form`, and then remove the `a` elements from the collection:

```
$('#Detail form').children().not('a').remove();
```

Note that I've used `remove`, which will actually remove any elements that are not `a` elements from the DOM. If you don't want that, then you can replace the call to `remove` with your call to `html`, which will simply remove all content from those elements.

Your current code will select all `form` elements that are descendants of `#Detail` and then try to remove all `a` elements from the collection. Since you have only selected `form` elements, there are obviously not going to be any `a` elements to remove!

Comment: `$('#Detail form *:not(a)').remove();` will be a bit more efficient as selection and filtering happens in one go.

Comment: @nadh FYI in my case your code doesn't work, I use jquerymobile and it destroys all built buttons